# Draw Quadratic Curve

Tags: c#, gdi+, system.drawing, quadratic

How can I draw Quadratic Curve through 3 points by using C# System.Drawing namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want to draw a quadratic curve that goes **through** three given points, or do you want to draw a [quadratic Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves) that **uses** three given points?

If what you want is a Bézier curve, try this:

```
private void AddBeziersExample(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Adds a Bezier curve.
    Point[] myArray =
             {
                 new Point(100, 50),
                 new Point(120, 150),
                 new Point(140, 100)
             };

    // Create the path and add the curves.
    GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();
    myPath.AddBeziers(myArray);

    // Draw the path to the screen.
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(myPen, myPath);
}
```

Which I just shamelessly lifted from the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addbeziers?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) for `GraphicsPath.AddBeziers()`.

**Edit**: If what you really want is to fit a quadratic curve, then you need to do a [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) or [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) on your points.  Perhaps [this answer from Ask Dr. Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20171122095301/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53796.html) will help.

Comment: Just to note that `GraphicsPath.AddBeziers()` takes `Point[]` array of at least 4 points. So if you want to draw the curve through 3 points, just pass the middle point two times: `Point[] points = { startPoint, middlePoint, middlePoint, endPoint };`